# append/add/unshift an object to the beginning of an response from an api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the data is returned from an api call i would like to add extra data to the data returned from the api call. So far i have got the data from the backend but i want to append extra data to the beginning of the data returned from the backend. I am unsure how to do this.

```
export const getMessageTemplates = (): Promise<
  ReadonlyArray<MessageTemplate>
> =>
  fetch(REACT_APP_BACKEND_LOCATION + "/api/template", {
    method: "get",
    credentials: REACT_APP_BACKEND_LOCATION === "." ? "same-origin" : "include",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  }).then(res=>res.json())
  .then(data=>data.unshift(
    {templateId: " ", category: "", title: "blank message", defaultTemplate:false}
    )).then(data=> data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.unshift` returns the length of the updated `data` array. Just change that implementation like so to return `data` explicitly :-

```
export const getMessageTemplates = (): Promise<
  ReadonlyArray<MessageTemplate>
> =>
  fetch(REACT_APP_BACKEND_LOCATION + "/api/template", {
    method: "get",
    credentials: REACT_APP_BACKEND_LOCATION === "." ? "same-origin" : "include",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  })
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(data=>
    {data.unshift(
    {templateId: " ", category: "", title: "blank message", defaultTemplate:false})
    return data;
    }).then((data)=>// do whatever with data);
```

Although you can prevent using that additional `then` chaining and the callback for `data` in the end and just use it in the previous one where you use `unshift`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        res.data.unshift({templateId: " ", category: "", title: "blank message", defaultTemplate:false});
        console.log(res.data) // new updated array
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lakshya's solution works perfectly for what you need and is a great answer.

If you'd like to get the same result you're looking for without using `unshift()`, you can also use the spread operator to return the new array to `data` inline without a return statement:

```js
export const getMessageTemplates = (): Promise<
  ReadonlyArray<MessageTemplate>
> =>
  fetch(REACT_APP_BACKEND_LOCATION + "/api/template", {
      method: "get",
      credentials: REACT_APP_BACKEND_LOCATION === "." ? "same-origin" : "include",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => [{ templateId: " ", category: "", title: "blank message", defaultTemplate: false }, ...data])
    .then((data) => /* your logic here */);
```